# MVC.NET Core / Razor: Submit value from Select box to DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

The form is defined in Add.cshtml:

```
@using bendinsnMusicApp.Models
@model Album

<h2>Add Album</h2>

<form action="Add" method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="Title" value="" autofocus />
    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span><br />
    Price: <input type="number" name="Price" value="" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span><br />
    Artist: <select name="Artist">
        @foreach (Artist artist in ViewBag.Artists)
        {
            <option value=@artist.ArtistID>@artist.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Artist"></span><br />
    Genre: <select name="Genre">
    @foreach (Genre genre in ViewBag.Genres)
    {
        <option value=@genre.GenreID>@genre.Name</option>
    }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Genre"></span><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The error occurs in the following action in my controller, AlbumsController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(Album a)
{
    var albums = _context.Albums;
    albums.Add(a);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    var albums2 = _context.Genres.ToList();
    ViewBag.Artists = _context.Artists.ToList();
    ViewBag.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
    return View("Index", albums2);
}
```

Specifically, when attempting to save the changes, the update fails because the foreign keys of the Album object, ArtistID and GenreID, are both 0 every time, and Artist and Genre are both null. For completeness, here is the Album class:

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; } 
}
```

It seems that some error is preventing the form from properly submitting the Artist and Genre fields, both of which are `select` elements. Further, I expect that even if the actual content of those elements was submitted, it would not include the FK values.

Note that ViewBag.Artists and ViewBag.Genres are defined as `_context.Artists.ToList()` and `_context.Genres.ToList()` respectively in the action to render the view. Each Genre and Artist includes a `Name` and `[class]ID`, and Artist has an associated text field called `Bio` as well.

The Albums table includes fields for AlbumID, ArtistID, GenreID, Price, and Title. The first three are ints, the second is a decimal, and the last is nvarchar.

What needs to be done to:

A) Submit the content of the `select` elements along with the rest of the form?

B) Use the ArtistID and GenreID values (`int`s in their respective classes) as arguments for filling the Albums table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of each select input needs to correspond to the field in the Model that the value will fill in when the Model Binding occurs.

Change the code:

```
<select name="Artist">
```

to

```
<select name="ArtistID">
```

and the same for the Genre select, name="GenreID"

That will allow the Model Binding to pick up those values correctly, and then you can use them in the Controller as you need.

Comment: It seems like the `asp-validation-for` property in the `span` element following each `select` needed to be changed as well, but with that variation, this seems to have worked.